# BigQuery streaming buffer data and deleting a table partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a workflow that relies on dropping a partition in BigQuery and recreating it with new data.

I am concerned about what might happen with data in the BQ streaming buffer at the moment that I delete the partition: Will it be deleted? Or is it possible that it will be added to the partition afterwards?

Let's say I do something like this:

1. Stream rows 1-10 to a BQ table, partition 20231010.
2. Wait one day.
3. Stream rows 11-20 to the BQ table, partition 20231010.
4. Immediately issue a command `bq rm -f 'mydataset.mytable$20231010`
5. Stream another rows 21-40 to the BQ table, partition 20231010.
6. Query `SELECT * FROM mydataset.mytable`

What are possible values that will be returned?

- Rows 21-40 - certainly
- Rows 11-20 - ?
- Rows 1-10 - certainly not

Comment: You will have only rows 21-40

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, when you issue a command to delete a partition, the behavior depends on whether there is streaming data in the partition at the time of deletion. When you delete a partition using `bq rm`, it only removes the metadata about the partition, not the actual data. In this case, the partition 20231010 metadata will be deleted, but the data will still exist in the background.

Rows `21-40` will certainly be returned in the query.

Rows `11-20` will not be returned in a standard query since the metadata for partition 20231010 was deleted. However, since the data is still there, if you query partition 20231010 specifically, you can retrieve rows **1-40**.

Rows `1-10` will not be returned in the standard query because the partition metadata has been deleted. To access the data in partition 20231010, you may need to query it using the special syntax for querying specific partitions or recovering the data if needed.

Comment: thanks so much. This is very useful to understand. Follow up: Will BigQuery know that it needs to remove all rows before the deletion, and add all rows after? Or is it possible that on the long term, rows pre-deletion will appear?